# Is it a Wrong Code in MSDN?

Tags: c#, msdn

I found the following code in MSDN ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664604%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) which appears to be wrong (compile-time error). Isn't it?

```
delegate void D(int x);
class C
{
   public static void M1(int i) {...}
   public void M2(int i) {...}
}
class Test
{
   static void Main() { 
      D cd1 = new D(C.M1);      // static method
      Test t = new C();         // <---- WRONG-------
      D cd2 = new D(t.M2);      // instance method
      D cd3 = new D(cd2);      // another delegate
   }
}
```

Consider this line:

```
Test t = new C();
```

The class **C** is not derived from the class **Test**, so this assignment will not compile. Am I am missing something here (some assumptions that I have not considered in the article?)

Also the following line would be wrong even if C class was derived from Test:

```
D cd2 = new D(t.M2);
```

Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's clearly wrong. Look at the next example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664605(v=vs.71).aspx, they use C c = new C(); there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That line should be

```
C t = new C();
```

You could also use (in new versions of C#)

```
var t = new C();
```

The only way that `t.M2` on the next line will be valid is if `t` has type `C`.

Comment: Given that that version of the page is referring to Visual Studio .NET 2003, it would be the former and not the latter. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @ClickRick: Well, we don't know what version of C# kami is using, but I agree that `var` wouldn't have been appropriate for that section of MSDN.  Edited to clarify.